# Auto generate pages links to navigation bar on Octopress

Tags: octopress

I created many pages under `tutorial` folder.

```
those pages are
tutorial/ruby
tutorial/python
tutorial/c
```

However, I can only see posts in my Octopress blog,
but pages can not be seem. only posts can be seem.

If I want to access those pages under tutorial,
I should type the link manually.

Is there anyway to generate the pages I create and auto create link to menu or navigation bar?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate the pages using the `rake generate`

Now add them to the navigation of your site.
Here are the docs on how to do it:
http://octopress.org/docs/theme/template/

> ***Changing the Navigation***
>
> To change or add links to the main navigation, edit `/source/_includes/custom/navigation.html` which looks like this:
>
> Navigation (source/_includes/custom/navigation.html)
>
> ```
> <ul class="main-navigation">
>     <li><a href="{{ root_url }}/">Blog</a></li>
>     <li><a href="{{ root_url }}/archives/">Archives</a></li>
> </ul>
> ```
>
> The href for each link begins with `{{ root_url }}` (this helps Octopress write urls differently if a site is deployed to a subdirectory).
>
> If you're deploying your site to a subdirectory like yoursite.com/octopress you'll want to add this to any links you add.